# Java computed properties

Tags: java

I use Jacob library to manipulate my Win32 application.
I got some java SomeClass which is an implementation of win32 SomeClass.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public String someProperty;

    public String getProperty(String propertyName){
         return SomeStaticSystemClass.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public String setProperty(String propertyName, String value){
         return SomeStaticSystemClass.getProperty(propertyName, value);
    }
}
```

How can I call getProperty or setProperty methods when I get or set "someProperty" field?

In Swift, for example, I can do something like that:

```
struct Rect {
var origin = Point()
var size = Size()
var center: Point {
    get {
        let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
        let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
        return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    }
    set(newCenter) {
        origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
        origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unclear as to what you're asking at the moment - do you literally just want to know how to call an existing method in Java? Or is there something more here?

Comment: Or there is `PropertyChangeListener` and friends, but it all depends on what exactly you're trying to do, which still isn't clear 5 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no concept of "property" in Java. That is, it is impossible to trigger a setter or a getter call by assigning a value to a field or reading a value from it.

A general pattern is to call getter and setter methods instead, keeping the field value private so it can only be accessed as a value within the class.

There is a tendency in the Java community to overuse getters and setters, automatically providing both for private fields (the situation in Java Beans). It is advisable though to first, define no getter/setter methods for data that should not be directly accessible from outside, second, work with final values wherever possible and thus define no setters for them, and third, use public fields for DTOs whose sole purpose is to transport data (see "Clean Code" by Uncle Bob).

Comment: From my understanding you should never directly access instance fields in java due to how class inheritance works. You should always use getters and setters. If class B extends class A, and in class B it overrides a getter, when accessing that getter method on an instance of class B but specified to type A( A a = new B() ), class B's overridden getter is called (as expected). But if you were to directly access an instance field in that same scenario, class A's instance field would be called and not B's (not expected). It's confusing but it makes sense. I will create a blog post demonstrating

Comment: Class inheritance works exactly the same way in e.g. python and there it is a standard practice to access fields directly. Getters provide a level of encapsulation, good to have normally, but not always. I would accept an argument though that you cannot satisfy an interface by field access, but can by methods; although I would question the value of an interface that defines getters.